# How to scale a range of values from 0-1 to 0-10

Tags: c#, math

I have developed a app which is allowed to play a recording on iOS. On iOS, the volume range is from 0 - 1 ie it returns either 0 or 1. For representational purpose I would like to scale that range to 0-10. How can I do that?

Comment: After reading a couple of comments by you. No matter if you truly only have two values for your scale or not, you cannot logically change a scale that contains two values to another scale that contains more due to the sole lack of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to scale it linearly<sup>(a)</sup>, it's a simple matter of multiplying it by ten. I hesitate to state the obvious (i.e., don't want to sound condescending) but, on the rather unlikely chance you don't know how to do that:

```
scaledValue = inputValue * 10;
```

Of course, if the *input* is what you desire to be in the range `0..10`, then you'd need to divide it by ten when passing it to the iOS functions that need `0..1`.

Just be certain that you're using floating point values of some description for both the input and output scales, otherwise you may run into issues where the scaling will not work as you expect (if you want an integer value from zero to ten, convert it to an integer as the final step, after all scaling has been done).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If the scaling you want is non-linear, you'll need to tell us the formula you want to use, keeping in mind that the C# expression will be remarkably similar to what you give. And of course, as any Spinal Tap fan will tell you, the best amplifiers go up to `11` :-)

Comment: That doesn't work because because the volume range gives only 2 values 0 and 1.

Comment: @Arti How would you want to change a scale that only has 2 values to another scale that has more? That does not make much sense at all... If it's a volume scale, I would assume it returns a floating point in the range 0 to 1, otherwise you would have the volume either off, or at max, which also makes no sense.

Comment: @Arti, if you're only getting `0` or `1` out of the OS, that will scale (quite correctly) to `0` and `10`. You don't have enough information to scale it any other way. I suspect that you're using integers at some point which is causing the floating point value in the range `0..1` to be limited to only `0` or `1` rather than the float it should be. You need to fix that.

Comment: Yes you are right, my mistake here. I have fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your number is float

```
float map(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max
{
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

`in_min -> in_max` is your input range

`out_min -> out_max` is your output range

Usage

```
float mappedValue = map(VALUE, 0, 1, 0, 10);
```

Referenced from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map

Answer (score 2):

Scaling is typically associated with multiplication. Here, you just have to apply a scale factor of 10, hence, multiply all your values by 10.

Comment: Multiplying all the values will not give me a range from 0-10. I have only 2 values 0  and 1 I would like to get range from 0,1,2,3,...10.